# In the Redux container pattern. Should 'connect' be in the components, or containers?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

At the moment, I have my connect statements in the containers. This is leading to me having to connect all individual states and actions in one large connect statement:

```
@connect(
  (state: RootState): Pick<App.Props, 'state1' & 'state2' & 'state3'> => {
    return { state1: state.state1, state2: state.state2, state3: state.state3 }
  },
  (dispatch: Dispatch<Action<Actions1 & Actions2 & Actions3>>): Pick<App.Props, 'action1' & 'action2' & 'action3'> => ({
    action1: bindActionCreators(omit(Actions1, 'Type'), dispatch),
    action2: bindActionCreators(omit(Actions2, 'Type'), dispatch),
    action3: bindActionCreators(omit(Actions3, 'Type'), dispatch)
  })
)
```

I'm then passing all the props in a tree to components like this:

```
<Component1 props={ this.props.action1 } />
<Component2 props={ this.props.action2 } />
```

This is working fine, but it does mean as we add new states to the Redux store, the container component is going to get larger and larger.

From my perspective, it would seem more sensible to pass these `@connect` in each individual component, meaning the component itself would be directly connect to the store.

Is there any reason we can't use the `@connect` in components, rather then containers?

Is there a reason this would be a bad practice?

Answer (score 2):

This might be a subjective pattern question, but maybe I can offer an objective-ish perspective.

Try to look at it without thinking about Container patterns specifically. Nothing is stopping you from injecting Redux directly at the component-level, but, that style of component is inherently less flexible than a component that simply operates props (from any container, Redux or otherwise).

E.g. if you had a `<ContactList>` component that self-injected `reduxState.listOfPeople`, that ContactList could not be re-used for any other container / list prop. A more useful ContactList is just one that looks for `<ContactList list={...}>` and the container can provide that however it wants, Redux or some other way.

Comment: This is a completely reasonable perspective, and another reason why the current way I'm doing it works. I was just curious if there were 'set rules' or any real reasons that moving to components would be 'bad practice'

Comment: IMO it is ideal for UI components to be blissfully unaware of their true purpose, and to just operate on data passed in via props. This leads to more reusable components. If a component injects Redux on itself, it is assuming a single purpose. So not a 'set rule' - like most things in web dev, plenty of opinions / options to go about things

Comment: Flexibility is definitely a huge advantage and I am definitely be onboard with this. Is it okay to have such a large @connect though? Is that expected from this pattern?

Comment: Containers that are tying the loose ends of several components will have a large connect() injection, I wouldn't worry about that. This has rarely bottlenecked in my experience, which you can combat with more container separation, selectors, etc.